# Dynamically add option group and option in select box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Add option and option group dynamically from ajax data.

```
<select name="catsndogs">
   <optgroup label="Cats">
        <option>Tiger</option>
        <option>Leopard</option>
        <option>Lynx</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

From ajax data i have this list of array

```
{
  Regular: [
    "S",
    "XS",
    "M"
  ],
  Small: [
    "em"
  ]
}
```

I need to add "Regular", "Small" as headings but under Regular I want the list of sizes and under Small it list their sizes, 
like here http://jsfiddle.net/sushilbharwani/Xp8YK/

But need to done this dynamically...can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that json1 is the `JSON` you are returning from the ajax, it can be done like this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 
var $cont = $('select');
var json1 = {"Regular": ["S", "XS", "M"],"Small": ["em"]};
   for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(json1).length;i++){
    var a = '<optGroup label = '+Object.keys(json1)[i]+'>';
      for(var j=0;j<json1[Object.keys(json1)[i]].length;j++){
         a = a+'<option>' + json1[Object.keys(json1)[i]][j] +'</option>'
       }
   $(a).appendTo($cont)
   }
   
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<body>
<select>

</select>
</body>
```